# Beamforming with NDP frames

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, ofdm

During beamforming, the Tx first sends NDP Announcement (which is a broadcast frame) thereby reaching all Rx in its area. And then it follows by sending NDP.

1. Is the 2nd frame (NDP) is also a broadcast frame?
2. What happens if Tx wants to implement beamform with a specific Rx.

Comment: Hi! What standard are you referring to? What does NDP stand for?

Comment: I am guessing that OP is talking about Null Data Packet in 802.11ac. Have a [Survival Guide](http://euro.ecom.cmu.edu/resources/elibrary/auto/802dot11ac_A_Survival_Guide.pdf).

Comment: Yes, NDP (Null Data Packet) 802.11n/ac std. It is used for beamforming